# Writing from firebase realtime database to List

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble adding values from my Firebase Realtime Database to a List. The values are being retrieved properly, and can be printed, however- I am unable to add these values to a list. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot collectionSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    collectionName = collectionSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    names.add(collectionName);
                    count = collectionSnapshot.child("progress").getValue(int.class);
                    numbers.add(count);
                    Toast.makeText(CollectionGraph.this, collectionName + count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

I'm attempting to use the values within the two arrays on a pie chart, however, upon running the app, I am met with an empty pie chart
[Empty output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqWuo.png)
[Firebase Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCgaG.png)

Comment: Can you edit the post to show the sample output and possibly how your real-time DB looks like as well, pls?

Comment: Not enough info to say for sure, but it sounds like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70178210/9473786) - are you making the pie chart immediately after declaring that callback? You should create the chart inside `onDataChange` or the chart will be created before the firebase call finishes

Comment: Agree with Tyle's comment. There is no way you can simply do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).